# Scala : match case syntax vs => S?

Tags: scala

```
 def phrase[T](p: Parser[T]) = new Parser[T] {
    def apply(in: Input) = lastNoSuccessVar.withValue(None) {
      p(in) match {
      case s @ Success(out, in1) =>
        if (in1.atEnd)
          s
        else
            lastNoSuccessVar.value filterNot { _.next.pos < in1.pos } getOrElse Failure("end of input expected", in1)
        case ns => lastNoSuccessVar.value.getOrElse(ns)
      }
    }
  }
```

The function above is found in `Scala`'s source code.

What confuses me is : `withValue`'s declaration is

`def withValue[S](newval: T)(thunk: => S): S`

then,

- what is the meaning of `=> S` ?
- and what is the relationship with `match case` syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `=> S` is anything that can give a `S`, either a literal or a function without parameter.

As parameter definition, a parameter *by-name*, it allows to not compute the `S` value when calling, but 'inside' `withValue` (and only when required). A kind of `lazy val` equivalent for parameter.

def foo: String = someComputation

withValue("literal")
   withValue(foo)
   // foo not called before passing to withValue

Comment: the `match case` here is as a function value ?

Comment: The `match` syntax is unrelated. It's plain pattern matching working with any value, literal or function result.

Answer (score 0):

The type `=> S` of the parameter `thunk` means that `thunk` is a *call-by-name* parameter.

Normally, when you pass an argument to a method, the argument is evaluated immediately before the method is called. With a call-by-name parameter, it is not evaluated when the method is called, but only when the method uses the argument.

This can be useful for expressions that have side effects or that are expensive to evaluate - you can avoid evaluating them at all if the method doesn't need the result of evaluating the argument.

In your example, the whole block `{ p(in) match { ... } }` is what's passed for the parameter `thunk` to the method `withValue`. The method `withValue` will evaluate the block only when necessary, instead of that the block is evaluated before `withValue` is called.

This has no direct relation with `match`.

Answer (score 0):

There are three separate issues:

1. passing function as parameter

`def withValue[S](newval: T)(thunk: => S): S`

`thunk` is function that transform whatever to `S`.

Easier example:

`def withValue[S](newval: T)(thunk: Long => S): S`

`thunk` is function that transform `Long` to `S`.

2. type classes

`S` type is determined when you pass `thunk` function to you method. Type classes are used to determine releations betwen types in method/class

http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html

3. match clause

`p(in)` just return `Success` or `Failure` that can be matched by `match/case`

http://mauricio.github.io/2014/02/17/scala-either-try-and-the-m-word.html